# Netty 5.0 object send and receive

Tags: object, serialization, netty

I am attempting to get to grips with netty and i confess i am having a hard time doing the simplest of thing with it, i cant really find much in the way of tutorials or any as of yet published material.

So on to the problem:

I have downloaded the example ObjectEcho example from http://netty.io/5.0/xref/io/netty/example/objectecho/package-summary.html

I have it set up on localhost and when i start it all up and run the client i get the following:

```
Jul 11, 2015 11:21:34 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
INFO: [id: 0x3b3ab260, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8007] RECEIVED: [id: 0x1f7374e8,       /127.0.0.1:49196 => /127.0.0.1:8007]
```

Excellent, next i tried to send a String from the client like so:

// Start the connection attempt.

```
 b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

 b.connect().channel().write("Hello");
```

On the server side in the serverhandler class i add within channelRead method the following:

```
  if(msg instanceof String){
      ctx.write((String)msg);
      System.out.println((String)msg);
      }
```

I was hoping i would thus see on console the word "Hello".

Instead i get nothing at all, so i am going to assume i am missing out a step, doing something terribly wrong or a mix of the two, any out there got the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your channelRead, the msg should be ByteBuffer, not a String. You should do as below:

```
ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf)msg;
byte[] req = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
buf.readBytes(req);
String body = new String(req, "UTF-8");
```